# Gradle, include all json files in my build directory

Tags: java, gradle, copy

hey all i want gradle to copy all my JSON files inside my source code into the same path under the build directory.

this is what i have in my gradle.build file

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/resources']
            include 'com/company/project/package/**/*.json','images/**/*.jpg', 'images/**/*.jpeg', 'images/**/*.png'
        }
    }
}
```

but the files are missing

thank you

Comment: `src/main/java`is for java files only. You should never put images, json etc under `src/main/java` (that's what `src/main/resources` is for!!!)

Comment: i have multiple classes in specific packages that need a JSON schema for each class that handle JSCON Schema validation, so JSON files are close to the class's for more easy use. holding another tree just for JSON will be harder to mange, but this is the solution i chose, can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it'll help but your code would be more future proof if you blacklisted `*.java` instead of maintaining a whitelist

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/resources']
            exclude '**/*.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had to delete the 'out' and 'build' folders, after that it just worked. excluding java is a good extra, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had to delete the 'out' and 'build' folders, after that it just worked...